# Python multiprocessing shared variables doesn't change

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing for my project at school but I have a problem with shared variables between multiple processes.

I'm making a game where you have 10 steps on a stair. Each step has a ledstrip and an ultrasone sensor. The ledstrip can light up green, orange and red. When stepping on green, you get one point, when stepping on orange, you get two points and stepping on red is game over. When stepping on green, the ledstrip turns from green to orange for four seconds and then turns red.

In this code, I'm simulating the stair with a list (first index is first step, 1 = green, 2 = orange and 3 = red). When starting, all ledstrips are turned red except the first step, that is green. When pressing enter (= stepping on first green step), the game will begin. Then random steps will light up green every time you input what step you want to step on (= stepping on it irl).

The code is far from done but I now want to convert this code to use multiprocessing because I need a function that runs at the same time as this code that is time based to turn the stept ledstrips orange and then red.

This is the code I have, that works:

```
import time
import random

feet = 0
steps = 10
start = False
lightUpLeds = 0

# 1 = green, 2 = orange, 3 = red
ledsorder = []
ledsorder.append(1)
for i in range(1, steps):
    ledsorder.append(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        if start:
            for i in range(0, steps):
                # print(i, feet)
                if i == int(feet):
                    # print("---")
                    ledsorder[int(feet)] = 2
                else:
                    rand = random.randint(0, 1000)
                    if rand < 300:
                        ledsorder[i] = 1
                        lightUpLeds += 1
            
            begin = int(feet) - 2
            end = int(feet) + 2

            if begin < 0:
                begin = 0
            
            if end >= steps:
                end = steps
            else:
                end += 1
            
            # print("begin, end", begin, end)
            
            hasGreen = False
            for i in range (begin, end):
                # print(i)
                if ledsorder[i] == 1:
                    hasGreen = True
            
            # print(hasGreen)
            if hasGreen != True:
                ledsorder[end] = 1
            
            lightUpLeds = 0
            for i in range (0, steps):
                if ledsorder[i] == 1:
                    lightUpLeds += 1

            print("light up leds:", lightUpLeds)
            print(ledsorder)
            feet = input("place your feet: ")
        else:
            print(ledsorder)
            input("Start game? (enter)")
            feet = 0
            start = True
```

And this is my attempt to convert it to multiprocessing:

```
import time
import random
import multiprocessing
import ctypes


def led_color_timer(feet, steps, start, lightUpLeds, newStep, ledsorder):
    while True:
        pass
        # print(ledsorder)
        # time.sleep(1)


def main_loop(feet, steps, start, lightUpLeds, newStep, ledsorder):
    while True:
        print(start, newStep)
        time.sleep(1)

        if start and newStep == False:
            for i in range(0, steps):
                # print(i, feet)
                if i == int(feet):
                    # print("---")
                    ledsorder[int(feet)] = 2
                else:
                    rand = random.randint(0, 1000)
                    if rand < 300:
                        ledsorder[i] = 1
                        lightUpLeds += 1
            
            begin = int(feet) - 2
            end = int(feet) + 2

            if begin < 0:
                begin = 0
            
            if end >= steps:
                end = steps
            else:
                end += 1
            
            # print("begin, end", begin, end)
            
            hasGreen = False
            for i in range (begin, end):
                # print(i)
                if ledsorder[i] == 1:
                    hasGreen = True
            
            # print(hasGreen)
            if hasGreen != True:
                ledsorder[end] = 1
            
            lightUpLeds = 0
            for i in range (0, steps):
                if ledsorder[i] == 1:
                    lightUpLeds += 1

            print("light up leds:", lightUpLeds)
            print(ledsorder)
            newStep.value = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

    feet = multiprocessing.Value("i", 0)
    steps = multiprocessing.Value("i", 10)
    start = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_bool, False)
    lightUpLeds = multiprocessing.Value("i", 0)
    newStep = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_bool, True)
    # 1 = green, 2 = orange, 3 = red
    ledsorder = manager.list()
    ledsorder.append(1)
    for i in range(1, steps.value):
        ledsorder.append(3)
    
    led_color_timer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=led_color_timer, args=(feet.value, steps.value, start.value, lightUpLeds.value, newStep.value, ledsorder))
    led_color_timer_process.start()
    main_loop_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_loop, args=(feet.value, steps.value, start.value, lightUpLeds.value, newStep.value, ledsorder))
    main_loop_process.start()

    while True:
        if start.value:
            if newStep.value:
                feet.value = int(input("place your feet: "))
                newStep.value = False
        else:
            print(ledsorder)
            input("Start game? (enter)")
            feet.value = 0
            start.value = True
            newStep.value = False
```

For testing, I'm printing two variables (start = False and newStep = True) in the main_loop process. When pressing enter at the bottom, the game should start and turn the variables (start = True and newStep = False) but print in main_loop still gives the original variables.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think your problem is that you are not passing the shared memory objects to your subprocesses, but instead are passing the values contained within them.  For example, you are passing `newStep.value` into the subprocess rather than passing `newStep`.  I believe that this defeats the whole purpose of wrapping values in these objects.  Change your subprocess to accept the shared memory objects themselves and then pull the values from them on the subprocess side, and I think you'll get better results.

Comment: I did what you said and it works! Thank you!